# how can I make dataflow job's ttl longer?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I cannot seem to find dataflow jobs on google cloud web console past the last 30 days. Is it possible to make that ttl longer? (I want to dig up an old job and see if there is any performance regression.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally good practice is to use Loggers at your pipeline to have all the logs accomodated at one place. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging
Please have a look at this which might help you attain longer TTL.
**By default its 30 days** which can be *configured*: https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods

How to configure: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/buckets#custom-retention